# import argparse fails, some setup/path issue?

Tags: python, macos, netbeans, argparse

I've written as minimal a python program using argparse as I can. Just three lines.

```
import argparse
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello World"
```

It gets the following error:

> File "/Users/pfarrell/sandbox/dbms/extractor/src/extractor.py", line
>   2, in 
>       import argparse ImportError: No module named argparse

This is the first python program I've ever written, so I can easily believe that I've not properly setup some python library path, etc.

This is running on OS-X

```
python --version  
Python 2.7.1  
pfarrell@way:~/sandbox/dbms/extractor/src$ python -c "import argparse; print argparse"  
<module 'argparse' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.pyc'>
```

More testing (thanks to the comments)

running it explicitly in the shell works, but running it inside netbeans fails:

#### shell only

```
python extractor.py -h  
Hello World  
usage: extractor.py [-h]  

optional arguments:  
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Running it as a script shows a completely different path. Looks like the netbeans setup needs a tweak or two

```
./extractor.py  -h  
/Users/pfarrell/sandbox/dbms/extractor/src  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib- scriptpackages  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC  
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages  
Hello World
```

#### executing inside netbeans

```
/Users/pfarrell/sandbox/dbms/extractor/src  
/Users/pfarrell/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2.1/jython-2.5.1/Lib  
/Users/pfarrell/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2.1/jython-2.5.1/Lib/site-packages  
/Users/pfarrell/sandbox/dbms/extractor/src  
__classpath__  
__pyclasspath__/  
Hello World
```

Comment: How did you run `extractor.py`?

Comment: Do you have another file named `argparse.py` in the same directory?

Comment: Does your second program work? You mention your one-line program "extractor.py" but then you provide your `python -c` test...

Comment: The "python -c" is a test that lists the results of where the module is.

No, there is no argparse in the directory.

One runs extractor.py in the shell, but I'm testing it within the netbeans python plugin. Since it works in the shell, clearly something is wrong in the netbeans setup.

Comment: That last exception seems like it is trying to run the extractor.py file with something else than Python. I think you need a hashbang line. Also note that this exception is not the one in the question title.

Comment: You have some issue with your path.  Put this in the `extractor.py` program at the top, before your `argparse` import.  `import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)`.  Then run from the command line, make note of the output, then do the same with your netbeans loader.  Also, what does your shebang look like?  You may also want to `print argparse.__file__` and see where it is loading from when it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all. The path had more than a few issues, as @sberry suggested.
I found that netbeans defaults to jpython, which is an older 2.5 version. It also can use the standard python 2.7.1, and when I use that, all is happyness and joy

Thanks a bunch.